# Geometry GRE question

Tags: geometry, circles

This is a GRE quesrtion, and I could not find the length to save my life, please help!

A circle with diameter PQ of length 10is internally tangent at P to a circle of radius 20. A sqare ABCD is constructed from A, B on the larger circle, CD tangent at Q for the smaller circle. and the smaller circle is outside ABCD.

What is the length of AB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x=|AB|$, the side of the square, let $O$ be the centre of the large circle, and let $M$ be the midpoint of $\overline{AB}$. If you make a sketch, you’ll find that $\triangle AMO$ is a right triangle with legs $\frac{x}2$ and $x-|OQ|=x-10$ and hypotenuse $20$. Thus,

$$(x-10)^2+\frac14x^2=400\;,$$

which is just a quadratic in $x$.

Comment: That's ingenious! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Akaichan: You’re very welcome!